# If $f^2$ is of bounded variation and càdlàg, is $f$ of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, bounded-variation

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $f^2$ is càdlàg and of bounded variation. Is $f$ of bounded variation?

If $f$ were to be continuous, I think that would be correct, following the proof in [$|f|$ is of bounded variation$\Rightarrow$ $f$ is of bounded variation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299679/f-is-of-bounded-variation-rightarrow-f-is-of-bounded-variation) But that proof doesn't work for càdlàg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=x\sin\frac1x$ is not BV on $[0,1]$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605241/is-fx-x-sin-frac1x-with-f0-0-of-bounded-variation-on-0-1)), but $f^2(x)=x^2\sin^2\frac1x$ is because its derivative
$$
(f^2)'(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\\ x\sin^2\frac1x-\sin\frac2x&\text{if }x>0\end{cases}
$$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1\lvert (f^2)'\rvert\,dx<\infty$.

Here $f$ is continuous, of course.